Fill multicol columns with two different texts one in each column
I'm writing down my physics class notes from my notebook to Latex. In the notebook I've used two column format where left there are exercises and solutions and on the right there are notes, facts, equations and aha-moments. How can I make a latex file where two essentially different texts go side by side down the page. And when one column reaches the bottom it'd just continue on in the next page. Multicol is nice but I didn't find a way to individually assign contents to each of the columns. Neither did the minipage environment fit for the job as it doesn't break nicely between pages, after all - such long texts aren't fit for minipage. I'd also like to change the widths of the colums or ratio of them on the page. Can anyone think of a solution for this kind of need?

Without knowing more, I guess that one text column + one note column using either \marginpar, package marginnote, package scrlayer-notecolumn or something like these would do it. But maybe I'm wrong, because your question is very general. So maybe you are searching for something completely different, e.g., something like parallel columns or tufte-latex.

@cabohah Yes parallel colums package was what I was looking for. The package for it is paracol. I'll make an answer for my question soon.

Does this answer your question? How can I create a two-column layout with different widths (and texts) for the two columns?

@cabohah maybe close the other way around? This question has a better answer because it has complete and minimal code.

@Marijn Don't think so. The other question has more alternatives and the answer here does not really show something, you cannot find in the paracol manual. Maybe combining the answers of both question would be the best. But this one is already shown in the Linked section at the other one. So the answer here can also be found there.

What I was looking for was package paracol which organizes two different texts to two side-by side columns. The package is mainly meant for comparing texts or showing original and translated text side by side but it works in this case well. Working example is
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
    \columnratio{0.65}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{4em}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \begin{leftcolumn}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
        \end{leftcolumn}
        
        \begin{rightcolumn}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        \end{rightcolumn}
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}

